# How to reshape Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe (transpose the row for each Category, and have these next to each other as columns and keep index same)

Tags: python, pandas

Very new to Pandas and was having trouble phrasing this so if there's already another post would appreciate link to it also. So I have a MultiIndex Dataframe and I want to reshape it.

I currently have something like this (multiple rows for Name with different Category):

```
                | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | ...| Col1000
Name | Category 
Jack     1        50.0   44.2   33.2   ...    NaN
         2        30.8   22.4   40.9   ...    12.0
         3        20.2   26.2   49.8   ...    9.0
Peter    1        30.0   22.5   40.9   ...    18.5
         2        34.9   28.2   21.6   ...    22.0
         ... etc
```

And want to get something like this:

```
                      Category 
Name |             1      2      3
Jack     Col1      50.0   30.8  20.2
         Col2      44.2   22.4  26.2 
         Col3      33.2   40.9  49.8
         ...
         Col1000   NaN    12.0  9.0
Peter    Col1      30.0   34.9  etc.
         Col2      22.5   28.2  ..
         Col3      40.9   21.6  ..
         ...       ...    ...
         Col1000   18.5   22.0
```

So essentially I want to transpose the row for each Category, and have these next to each other as columns and keep index Name in the final dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

edit: quick sample code:

```
index1 = pd.Index(["Jack","Jack","Peter", "Peter"])
index2= pd.Index(data=[1,2,1,2], name="Category")
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[54,21,11,99], "Col2":[22,44,12,98], "Col3":[22,25,15,2], "Col4":[88,77,45,56]})
df= df.set_index([index1,index2])
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stack` and `unstack`:

```
df.stack().unstack('Category')
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! Very swift.